# Magento on my MAMP server will sometimes not load anything

Tags: macos, magento, magento-1.7, mamp

I installed Magento a 4 days ago on my MacBook. Everything that day worked with no problems.

But today when I refresh a page sometimes not all the time the page returns blank.

It gets even weirder when I check the headers return by the server I get a Status Code 200.

Here are some screenshot of Google Chrome developer bar:

[image: Situation]

[image: Headers]

I feel that this problem is related to this one: [It seems that not all of my HTML page loads in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113521/it-seems-not-all-my-html-from-my-page-seems-to-load/17781739?noredirect=1#17781739)

I haven't found any solutions to that one either.

Also I am unable to access the admin section of the website (//127.0.0.1:8888/Editions_Panda/magento/admin). I just get this error:

```
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Allot of my server informations are found in the second image. If you need more information please do ask.

**UPDATE**

I found this in my Apache error logs, after I refresh one of the pages that did not want to load:

```
[Thu Jul 25 04:18:04 2013] [notice] child pid 46575 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Jul 25 04:18:08 2013] [notice] child pid 46576 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the caching in MAMP from XCache to APC or something else.